# How to select matching row in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have table like below

```
+--------+---------+------------------------------------+
|   Id   |  Name   |              DataID                |   
+--------+---------+------------------------------------+
|   1    |   xyz   |       111,222,333,444              |
|   2    |   xxz   |       555,666,777                  |
|   3    |   xyx   |       888,999,000,001              |
|   4    |   yyz   |       010,011,100,200              |
|   5    |   xyy   |       600,500,400,300,555          |
|   6    |   yyy   |       111,700,800,900              |
|   7    |   zyz   |       050,0150,025,550,950,888     |
|   8    |   xzz   |       800,786                      |
|
|
|
|  1123  |   aaa   |       111,444,666,888              |
|  1124  |   bbb   |       889,998,777                  |
+--------+---------+------------------------------------+
```

and also having some list of `DataID = (786,333,500,777)`. So now i want to check this list with DataID column. For example now row 8 has 786 in DataID column and row 1 has 333, row 5 has 500, row 1124 & 2 has 777. Now i want get this records as output. Just like given below. Please someone help me on it , sorry if my bad English and if my question was very basic. But please someone help on it. Expecting output like below

```
+--------+---------+------------------------------------+
|   Id   |  Name   |              DataID                |   
+--------+---------+------------------------------------+
|   1    |   xyz   |       111,222,333,444              |
|   2    |   xxz   |       555,666,777                  |
|   5    |   xyy   |       600,500,400,300,555          |
|   8    |   xzz   |       800,786                      |
|  1124  |   bbb   |       889,998,777                  |
+--------+---------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: So you're telling us each row has more than one data value embedded in the DataID field as comma separated data? This is not a good design.

Comment: Agree but i have no options now except this, this is for some report and analyze purpose i am asking. Table already in Production can't change

Comment: In which case, don't bother with an RDBMS. Do something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('777', DataID)
```

That should return xxz and bbb

Agree with commenter above, this is not a good way to handle data.

Comment: Is it possible to get all in on shot ? Something like this --> SELECT name FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('786,333,500,777', DataID)    to get all matching rows just shown in question

Answer (score 1):

Normally would not add another answer, but you asked a different twist on a similar question.

If you want, you can do this:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE CONCAT(',', DataID, ',') REGEXP ',(222|777|400),'
```

and you'll get back xyz, xxz, xyy, bbb

I doubt anyone would consider this to be optimal, but it will do what you're asking.